# Yii Merge other extension with dcclassified

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am new to Yii framework, this may be a stupid question. I spent some time to resolve this but couldn't

I downloaded dcclassied script from [here](http://code.google.com/p/dclassifieds-free-php-classifieds-script/). Its working fine.

Then I integrated [Yii-user-management](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user-management/) extension

This also work fine, if I access direct with URL. But here I want to merge both in one. So that both will use same theme. I tried to include widget in view file

```
/var/www/html/dclassifieds/themes/basic/views/site/index_tpl.php
```

however the following is not working.

```
<? $this->widget('application.modules.user.components.LoginWidget'); ?>
```

I am getting following error
**include(YumUserLogin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

[image]

can anyone help me here?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Could you care to enter some error message or description "how it is not working"? Do you have any exception, error, warning, or application works, but widget is not displayed?

Comment: error added with question.

Comment: yii framework do not have more support, its tough to get solution of single issue.

Comment: (a) add a _text_ (copy-paste) of your error, **not** _an image_ (it is completely not readable, at least for me, too small); (b) Yii has a **great support**, but not in here -- use [Yii Forum](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/) for this purpose.

Comment: I am getting following error include(YumUserLogin.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Seems, that your "Yii User Management" extension has incorrect path and is not being loaded correctly. Check paths and path aliases in your configuration file. Double check Yii User Management's installation guide etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import files of extensions in main config. This config is located in protected/config/main.php